# Detect enter in keypress event node.js rawmode

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a simple commandline tool to allow commandline input to a node.js server.
I am trying to make a buffer, so the user can press up and see the last command. To do that I have set

```
require('tty').setRawMode(true);
```

And detects all keypress with:

```
process.stdin.on('keypress', function (letter, key) {
    if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
        process.exit();
    } else if (key && key.enter) {
        write(letter);
        msgFired(buffer[bufferPos]);

        bufferPos += 1;
        buffer[bufferPos] = "";
    } else {
        write(letter);
        buffer[bufferPos] += letter;
    }
});
```

This does not detect enter-presses.

Are there a way to detect when a whole line is fires (as when RawMode is false) alongside with the keypress event? If not, how I detect the enter-press?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, your only error is that this:

```
else if (key && key.enter) {
```

should be this:

```
else if (key && key.name == 'enter') {
```

Comment: Yes, I figured. I couldn't post my own solution because of an 8 hour rule... Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution myself. To check for enter, the appropriate test is:

```
if (key && key.name == 'enter')
```

Here is a solution that works fairly well:

```
var allowedKeys = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøåABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ1234567890!- ";
process.stdin.on('keypress', function (letter, key) {
    if (key && key.ctrl && key.name == 'c') {
        listen = false;
        log("");
        process.exit();
    } else if (key && key.name == 'enter') {
        write('\n');
        msgFired(buffer[bufferPos]);

        buffer[bufferPos] = "";
    } else if (allowedKeys.indexOf(letter) != -1) {
        write(letter);
        buffer[bufferPos] += letter;
    }
});
```

The keynames (key.name) are fairly easy to guess. Tab is 'tab', enter is 'enter', arrow up is 'up' etc.

I hope this was helpful to anyone...

Edit: Note that I added a list of allowed characters, so the code does not crash on strange characters like ctrl + 3.